# Architecture of RRAM puf

Tags: puf

[Design, Analysis and Application of Embedded Resistive RAM-based Strong Arbiter PUF](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=8443101)

Can anyone explain the Global column and Local Column and the fig.5(a) and how MUX logic is related to fig. 5(a) and how the formula for the configurable stage in Table 2 is related to fig.6.

Comment: Hello there!  It will expand the readership and the chances of an informative answer to your question if you find an alternative link.  This one's a pay to view type.

Comment: IEEE is apparently a teapot right now (HTTP 418), so I can't even log in.